# Edit on mobile is badly laid out

Tags: bug, mobile-web

I'll let this speak for itself:

[image: Screen]

Note the gray "already all the way left" overlay, meaning I can't scroll the unseen areas into view. I also can't zoom out (already at max).

Apologies for giant image, I'm mobile. ;)

Comment: Does this happen with every edit?  Or just that specific question?  Which OS and Browser and version?  It looks like Chrome, but don't want anyone to assume.  And if it is only that question - which question is it?

Comment: @psubsee2003 So far only that question, but I ended up there by reviewing a suggested edit via visiting the question itself (that is, I was on the question first and saw a pending edit) and clicked `Improve Edit`. I do not think it is question specific, but have only the one data point (editing this question works just fine).